# Why doesn't my Y axis update in D3?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, scale, axis

I am trying to update my Y-axis. The graph starts with a Y-axis from 0-700. A new dataset is loaded and this is to be changed to 0-9 instead. I use the following code to update my scale followed by calling my axis, zoom and circle data points so they can use the new scale, but nothing changes.

```
function updateScaleY(newHeight){

    console.log(d3.max(newHeight, Number));
    var yScale = d3.scale.linear()
        .domain([0, d3.max(newHeight, Number)])
        .range([height, margin.bottom]);

    SVG.select(".x.axis").call(xAxis);
    SVG.select(".y.axis").call(yAxis);
    SVG.selectAll("circle").attr("cx",function(d){return xScale(d)}).attr("cy",function(d){return yScale(d)});
    zoom.y(yScale);
}
```

Comment: Why is the old height still in .range([height, ?

Comment: You need to assign the new scale to the axis component as well for it to be redrawn properly.

Comment: @Jonast92 Because the height is supposed to be the same height as the entire svg, but I want the scale to fix it so that the graphs y-axis only has small values such as 0-9

Comment: As @LarsKotthoff points out, you are creating a completely new scale but your axis is still associated with the old scale.  You can either pass your new scale to the axis, *or* just never create a new scale in the first place -- instead, call the domain and range methods on your old y scale to update it instead.

Comment: Oh wow it took 2 of you to made the obvious obvious for me. My goal was to update the existing scale, not create a new one. That fixed some problems for me, although it still has some problems. It'll be easier to look through now as I can find more sense with it